# When I switch tabs, the content (StreamBuilder) of the previous tab is lost, leaving a blank page

Tags: flutter

I have two tabs, in each one the content is a StreamBuilder.
The StreamBuilder returns a column with a text field to search on a ListView and another StreamBuilder, the latter returns a ListView. When I move to another tab and subsequently return to the previous one, leaving a blank page.
When I move to another tab and subsequently return to the previous one, the content is lost, leaving a blank page. How can you avoid this?
Here is the relevant code:

```dart
class ListaCredencialesCapturistaPantalla extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "ListaCredencialesCapturistaPantalla";
  const ListaCredencialesCapturistaPantalla({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListaCredencialesCapturistaPantallaState createState() => _ListaCredencialesCapturistaPantallaState();
}

class _ListaCredencialesCapturistaPantallaState
extends State<ListaCredencialesCapturistaPantalla>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<CredencialModelo> _listaCredencialesActivos = <CredencialModelo>[];
  final List<CredencialModelo> _listaCredencialesFinados = <CredencialModelo>[];
  final StreamController<List<CredencialModelo>> _controladorStreamActivos = StreamController<List<CredencialModelo>>();
  Stream<List<CredencialModelo>> get _streamActivos => _controladorStreamActivos.stream;
  final StreamController<List<CredencialModelo>> _controladorStreamFinados = StreamController<List<CredencialModelo>>();
  Stream<List<CredencialModelo>> get _streamFinados => _controladorStreamFinados.stream;

  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controladorStreamActivos.close();
    _controladorStreamFinados.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _construyeInterfaz();
  }

  Widget _construyeInterfaz() {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Listado de Credenciales'),
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                icon: Constantes.ICONO_USUARIO_ACTIVO,
                text: 'Activo',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Constantes.ICONO_USUARIO_FINADO,
                text: 'Finado',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            _construyeSeccionBusquedaListado(EstatusUsuario.activo),
            _construyeSeccionBusquedaListado(EstatusUsuario.finado),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Constantes.ICONO_AGREGAR,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, AgregaCredencialPantalla.id);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _construyeSeccionBusquedaListado(EstatusUsuario estatusUsuario) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.listaCredenciales(estatusUsuario),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.exclamationCircle),
                Text('Sin credenciales'),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Constantes.COLOR_INTERFAZ,),
          );
        }

        List<CredencialModelo> listaCredenciales = <CredencialModelo>[];

        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> elemento in snapshot.data!.docs) {
          listaCredenciales.add(CredencialModelo.fromMapCredencial(elemento.data()));
        }

        if (estatusUsuario == EstatusUsuario.activo) {
          _listaCredencialesActivos.clear();
          _listaCredencialesActivos.addAll(listaCredenciales);
        }
        else {
          _listaCredencialesFinados.clear();
          _listaCredencialesFinados.addAll(listaCredenciales);
        }

        return _construyeBusquedaListado(estatusUsuario);
      }
    );
  }

  Widget _construyeBusquedaListado(EstatusUsuario estatusUsuario) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _construyeCampoBusqueda(estatusUsuario),
        _construyeListaFiltrable(
          estatusUsuario,
          estatusUsuario == EstatusUsuario.activo ?
            _listaCredencialesActivos :
            _listaCredencialesFinados
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _construyeCampoBusqueda(EstatusUsuario estatusUsuario) {
    return RoundedIconTextFormField(
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
      inputFormatters: [FormateoTextoMayusculasInput()],
      labelText: 'Búsqueda',
      prefixIcon: Constantes.DATO_ICONO_BUSQUEDA,
      onChanged: (String busqueda) {
        _busquedaCredencial(busqueda.toUpperCase(), estatusUsuario);
      },
      validator: (String? busqueda) {},
    );
  }

  void _busquedaCredencial(String busqueda, EstatusUsuario estatusUsuario) {
    if (busqueda.isNotEmpty) {
      List<CredencialModelo> listaResultados =
        (estatusUsuario == EstatusUsuario.activo ?
          _listaCredencialesActivos :
          _listaCredencialesFinados
        ).where(
        (elemento) {
          return elemento.curp!.contains(busqueda) || elemento.apePat!.contains(busqueda) ||
          elemento.apeMat!.contains(busqueda) || elemento.nombre!.contains(busqueda) ||
          elemento.municipio!.toString().contains(busqueda);
        }
      ).toList();

      (estatusUsuario == EstatusUsuario.activo ?
        _controladorStreamActivos :
        _controladorStreamFinados).sink.add(listaResultados);
    }
    else {
      (estatusUsuario == EstatusUsuario.activo ?
        _controladorStreamActivos :
        _controladorStreamFinados
      )
      .sink
      .add(estatusUsuario == EstatusUsuario.activo ?
        _listaCredencialesActivos :
        _listaCredencialesFinados
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _construyeListaFiltrable(EstatusUsuario estatusUsuario, List<CredencialModelo> listaCredenciales) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<CredencialModelo>>(
      key: ValueKey(listaCredenciales),
      initialData: listaCredenciales,
      stream: estatusUsuario == EstatusUsuario.activo ? _streamActivos : _streamFinados,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<CredencialModelo>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.exclamationCircle),
                Text('Sin resultados'),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }

        return _construyeListaCredenciales(snapshot.data!);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _construyeListaCredenciales(List<CredencialModelo> listaCredenciales) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: listaCredenciales.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          return _construyeCredencial(listaCredenciales[position]);
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way...

Create a StatefulWidget (it's technically a new page) instead of a simple Widget.

Something Like that:

```
class ConstruyeSeccionBusquedaListado extends StatefulWidget {
  final EstatusUsuario estatusUsuario;
  const ConstruyeSeccionBusquedaListado({Key? key, required this.estatusUsuario}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ConstruyeSeccionBusquedaListado> createState() => _construyeSeccionBusquedaListado();
}

class _construyeSeccionBusquedaListado extends State<ConstruyeSeccionBusquedaListado> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ConstruyeSeccionBusquedaListado> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<Object>(
      stream: null,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Container();
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

And on your TabBarView do the following:

```
TabBarView(
  children: [
    ConstruyeSeccionBusquedaListado(estatusUsuario: EstatusUsuario.activo),
  ],
)
```

Don't forget to put the:

```
with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<>
```

and the:

```
@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

on your StatefulWidget.

This worked for me.

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19116